# What is an origin and solution for "port 9000: Connection refused" error?

Tags: 14.04, networking, java, connection, hadoop

I am stuggeling with `port 9000: Connection refused` error.

I work on `Ubuntu 14.04` and faced the problem when trying to run `Hadoop` in a non-distributed mode, as a single Java process (compare [Hadoop 2.4.1 documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation)). I tried to follow Hadoop Wiki suggestions on this error ([hadoop/ConnectionRefused](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused)) but I did not succed (I am a beginner `Ubuntu` user and find it difficult even to 100% understand the suggestions given). I posted [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused) from which I conclude that I have some general problem with `port 9000 Connection`.

**telnet** output:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:~$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

**nmap** output:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:~$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-27 11:09 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp open  ipp
902/tcp open  iss-realsecure

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

**Netcat** configuration:

I tried to make use of the following command to force the 9000 port to be open:

```
nc -k -l 9000
```

but it did not work well (I was still not able to perform the standlone operation mentioned and linked above).

Judging from my google research results, I see that the problem is quite common and poses a huge struggle especially for those who are not good at "admin-job-related issues". As I belong to those, I kindly ask for answers to the following questions:

- **Q1**: What is the origin of such problem in general? (Some *for a layman* introductory words / references about basic issues connected to ports / connections etc. would be very very welome).
- **Q2**: How to deal with this problem?

**Update.**

`sudo netstat -nlp | grep :9000`

returns nothing.

Comment: Are you sure the hadoop process is actually running / listening on port 9000? please add the output of `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :9000` to your question.

Comment: Hi @steeldriver , thank you for your attention! I updated my post.

Comment: Based on the `netstat` output, the most likely explanation is that the hadoop process has either failed to start, or is not listening on port 9000.

Comment: Please note it is a  Hadoop  operation in **standalone mode**. According to the [documentation hadoop-modes-explained-standalone](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation), I am not expected to perform any configuration which *makes Hadoop listening on port 9000* (unless I misunderstood something).

Comment: dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/352868/i-cant-connect-to-hadoop-port-9000 Please see if the accepted answer gets you on the right track

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind , thank you for your attention. I had visited this post (and tried the solutions provided) before posting this one. A careful reader would even notice my comment there, dated Apr 26 at 20:42  :) Unfortunately, the solution that solved an issue in that case ("i got overlapping ip ports with some apps on my host machine (...) `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:9000)`afterwards everything was ok") does not work in mine case (in my case `sudo lsof -t -i:9000` reports nothing).

Comment: it really looks like the hadoop process is just not running. you can take a look at `ps -aux` if you can find the process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to ***make*** my service listen to the port 9000 by adding to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file the following line:

```
Port 9000
```

I followed this [serverguide/openssh-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) (it contains also some important remarks about making a copy of the original file, restarting the sshd server application etc.)

After this I can see:

**telnet** output:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:~$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

**nmap** output:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:~$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-01 18:28 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00023s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
9000/tcp open  cslistener

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

**netstat** output:

```
martakarass@marta-komputer:~$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep :9000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16397/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      16397/sshd
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR first, more details following:**

"Connection refused" is the error you get when you try to connect to a service on a computer or server (or locally on your own computer) when the said service is either not listening on the specified TCP port (wrong port or service not started), or when a firewall explicitly rejects a connection instead of ignoring the request (not very common behavior).

**And now a little more detail:**

It can only happen with TCP (UDP services are sessionless) and this error is indeed very common for sys admins.

When a client application connects to a TCP service, it'll send a first packet with the SYN flag set. If we simplify, there are two possible answers to that:

- The server actualy listens on the required TCP port and replies with a SYN-ACK packet to acknowledge the SYN packet, after which the clients rends an ACK packet to "confirm" to the server that the SYN-ACK was received. That's the moment where you have established a TCP session, and when you can start "talking" with the server.
- The server receives your SYN packet, but isn't listening on the requested port. The connection is rejected with a packet that has the RST (reset) flag set. This is 99% of the time when you get the infamous "connection refused".

**How do I fix this ?**

Well, there are a few things you can check: Are you querying the right port on the client side ? Is your service started ? Is it listening on the right port ?

Those three questions will generally help you solve your issue.

Quick generic command to be entered on the **server** (the machine that runs the service)

Checking that the service is listening on the expected port

```
ss -nat | grep <enter port number here> | grep LISTEN
```

Some people on older systems might also use this

```
netstat -an | grep <enter port number here> | grep LISTEN
```

If you don't see anything here that looks like your port number, your service is either not started or not listening on the port number you specified.

Checking that the service is running

```
service <service name> status
```

Comment: I should also add that this question (and its answer) is very different from http://askubuntu.com/questions/352868/i-cant-connect-to-hadoop-port-9000.

The other question is hadoop related, while the OP here wanted information that is generic to all "Connection refused" errors. Hadoop here is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Hi @Marc-Olivier Barre, thank you a lot for this answer. I assume "my *service*" is, in this case, the same as "the *client*" and equals my single machine (please correct me if I am wrong). Do I understand well that I "myself" (my machine) want to connect with "myself" and it is not possible because it, most likely, is not listening on the port 9000? (I do not understand how " Is your service started ?" could be my case.) In my case `ss -nat | grep 9000 | grep LISTEN` returns nothing. Could you please provide some guide on ***how to make** my service listen on the port 9000*?

Comment: Little explanation for the comment above: *I do not understand how " Is your service started ?" could be my case*  because, as I understand, "my service" is my machine and when I try to perform the operation on the machine it means that the *machine is*, obvioulsly, *running*.

Comment: ok, vocabulary needs a little explanation: _service_ is hadoop in the OP case. _Client_ is generally a browser, or the telnet program for instance. _Server_ is generally the machine running the service. _Client program_ and _service_ can be located on the same machine (i.e. your laptop). In the case the _server_ is just your laptop.

Comment: "In your hadoop configuration files, does fs.default.name and mapred.job.tracker refer to localhost? If so, then Hadoop will only listen to port 9000 and 9001 on the loopback interface, which is inaccessible from any other host. Make sure fs.default.name and mapred.job.tracker refer to your machine's externally accessible host name" -- source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855808/hadoop-job-tracker-only-accessible-from-localhost

Comment: Hi @Aravinda ,  thank you for your comment. I am not sure if I am missing domething, but I understand from the post you sourced that "Hadoop will only **listen to port 9000 and 9001 on the loopback interface**, which is inaccessible from any other host" and, as "The loopback device is a special, virtual network interface that your computer uses to communicate with itself" it **sould be sufficient for what I am in need for** when it comes to  runing `Hadoop` in a non-distributed mode, on a single machine - **isn't it?**

Comment: According to stackoverflow answer, you may check the config files !!

Comment: I am having similar problem with with remote xdebug with netbeans. I can see with netstat that netbeans is listening on port 9000. Nevertheless from the remote server I can not telnet my machine with netbeans. What should be done on this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try do disable iptables:

```
sudo service iptables stop && sudo service ip6tables stop
```

Then restart hadoop. If this helped you need make proper configuration for your firewall.

Comment: Hi @UNIm95 , thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention in the post that this is not my case (I investigated this following suggestions in other [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused) that I linked in my question here). Please note I have eventually found a solution which I describe in the answer I markeds as "accepted" here.